# How to write Web API, Self hosting, Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, asp.net-web-api

I can't make sense of this.  I keep getting an exception

Exception thrown: 'System.AggregateException' in mscorlib.dll, with a message: "Internal error in the expression evaluator." and no Inner Exception!

I can't find where the error is coming from other than when the server is being started, this Line: _server.OpenAsync().Wait();

I thought it would be a good idea to use DI and I though my problems were coming from Autofac but as you can see I have remarked it all out and I'm still getting this exception.  The pertinent code is in the last method.  Please take a look at the code:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Threading;
using System.Reflection;
using ServicesUtilities;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.SelfHost;
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Integration.WebApi;

namespace SeviceMerge
{

    partial class MergeService : ServiceBase, IQuasiServiceBase
    {
        private HttpSelfHostServer _server;
        private bool _runOnStart;
        public InjectionService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _runOnStart = Config.Run;
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            WebApiListener();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            _runOnStart = false;

            _server.CloseAsync().Wait();
            _server.Dispose();
        }
        void IQuasiServiceBase.OnStart(string[] args, bool isBatchMode)
        {
            OnStart(args);
        }

        void IQuasiServiceBase.OnStop()
        {
            OnStop();
        }

        bool IQuasiServiceBase.PauseCheck()
        {
            return false;
        }

        bool IQuasiServiceBase.StopCheck()
        {
            return false;
        }

        private void WebApiListener()
        {
            var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:26675");

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                "Presents",
                "api/{controler}/{id}",
                new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            _server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config);
            _server.OpenAsync().Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my Controller code:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace AEMtoParmedInject.Controllers
{
    public class AemToParmedMergeController : ApiController
    {
        private ILogger _logger;
        private IWorkTheMachine _worker;
        public AemToParmedMergeController()
        {
            _logger = new Logger();
            //_worker = worker;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage Index()
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                Content = new StringContent(
                    "<html>" +
                        "<head>" +
                        "</head>" +
                        "<body>" +
                            "<p>By click on the button below you are signaling the AEM to Parmed Merge service to perform it task</p>" +
                            "<form>" +
                                "<input type='submit' action='Index' value='Integrate AEM Content'>" +
                            "</form" +
                        "</body>" +
                    "</html>",
                    Encoding.UTF8,
                    "text/html"
                )
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at the `AggregateException` in the debugger. What's inside it? (InnerExceptions property)

Comment: No much, the exception message says: "Internal error in the expression evaluator." and no inner exception. Thanks...

Comment: I have added my controller code as well

Answer (score 0):

Everything in .net core starts with a simple console application and here I  give you 5 simple steps that you can use in order to self-host a Web API / Web APP in a worker service and host the final .exe in your windows services, even you can host in Linux Systemd with little changes.

I've created a very simple Worker-Service Web-API template that exists in my GitHub profile. The following steps work 100%, but if you faced any problem, you can ask here or you can clone the template from my GitHub and use it and read the documentation there.

Do the following steps:

1. Create a .net core console application.
2. Install packages "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" and "Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices" using NuGet.
3. Create a Worker.cs file which will handle your worker service. put the following codes inside:

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace WorkerServiceWebAppTemplate
{
    public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

        public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
                await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

4. Create a Startup.cs file which will handle your web host and create a simple GET API in the root address and responsible to show a simple message. you can extend it. put the following lines of codes in your Startup.cs file:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace WorkerServiceWebAppTemplate
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            else
                app.UseHsts();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
                {
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

5. Finally to start worker service and host your Web API inside your worker service, and also in order yo allow your published .exe file to be able to be host in windows services, use the following codes in your Program.cs:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace WorkerServiceWebAppTemplate
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        private static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseWindowsService()
                .ConfigureServices((hostBuilderContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                })
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That question was asked a long time ago.  There was no .net core...  Thanks for the response...